# How can I validate a secret sent to a server?

Tags: php, http, php-5.3

I dont remeber how I did this before but I had done this and was wondering if someone can help me.

I am posting data to another page using a GET request with some parameters in the URL. I want to validate the parameter at the receiving end. The last time I did it by adding a secret and then hashing it, but now I can't remember how.

Comment: Have a google for CSRF - it's been covered many times before. Look out for stuff by Chris Schifflett and Stefan Esser (Chris's CSRF redirector is bit dodgy though)

Answer (score 2):

If you are validating if the parameters are from the source you intend them to come from, i.e.: I only receive parameters if users came from page1.php here's what you do

1. User goes to page1.php, a token is generated and placed in his $_SESSION. The hashed token is added to the form on page1.php (or link, or whatever)
2. The user sends the parameters to page2.php.
3. You check if a hash exists and if the token in $_SESSION, when hashed, is equal to the one sent by the user

Do remember that in this case you are only validating if the parameters are sent by a known source. Alway do input validation to check if the received values are acceptable values!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is (you already said it) add a hash of the `GET` values. The advantage of this approach is that the link (if to be published) is "complete" in the sense that you're not relying on other data via active session and the like. In other words, the link comes with its own validation information.

I would do this like so:

**Calculate the hash**

1. Sort the array of `GET` keys and values (because the parameter order should be ignored, e.g., `?a=1&b=2` yield the same hash as `?b=2&a=1`)
2. Calculate a [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) of the array prepended with a *fixed salt*, i.e. `hashFunc(concat(GETArray, fixedSalt))`
3. Add the `hash` from (2) to the `GET` parameters.

**Validating the  values**

1. Extract the `hash` parameter and sort the *remaining* array of `GET` keys and values
2. Calculate the hash for the sorted array from (1) - same procedure as (2) in the list above
3. Check that the calculated hash value matches the values from the `GET` parameter.

The **fixed salt** is used to make sure, that a knowledgeable person cannot "guess" your hashing algorithm and thus tamper with the data (unless he also knows the fixed salt, of course :) ).

---

**Example: `a=1`, `b=2`**

- Sorted array: `array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);`
- Hash: `xyz` (via `hashFunc()` on concat of `sortedArray` and `'mySa1t'`)
- GET params: `?a=1&b=2&hash=xyz`, see [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)
- ...
- Hash: `xyz`, remaining GET array, sorted: `array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);`
- Calculated hash: `xyz` (via `hashFunc()` on concat of `srecievedSortedArray` and `'mySa1t'`)
- `xyz` == `xyz`, yaj!

Comment: Disclaimer: The steps above are a little verbose. Some steps may be ignored, depending on the method used to build links (queries) and recieve data (`GET` parameters).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, nobody is doing such "validations".

In fact, there is no *data* being sent to another page via url. It just doesn't make sense to send some data on the server where it's already exists.

You are taking query string wrong. It doesn't send any data, it just identifies some page.

Whole page address being an URL, an unique address of a page.

If you have a page on your server responding to some URL, no such sealing is required.

Instead of such hashing you have to validate your parameters.